# Make function stop when hovering over an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a function that runs when hovering a parent div and it should stop working when hovering a child div because there is another function for that.

```
<div class="parent">
//Here the function should work

<div class="child">Text </div> // here it should stop working

//Here the function should work
</div>
```

I am conditioning it to work on parent div with

`if ($('.parent').is(':hover')) {do stuff}`

and I am interested in having something like this:

```
if ($('.parent').is(':hover') AND NOT $('.child').is(':hover')) { do stuff }.
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for the mouse to enter the child without going through the parent before ?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link

Comment: In your child hover event listener, call [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: @dystroy nope. first you must go through parent

Comment: Could you explain your use case? Are you building a menu?

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation()` like bellow

```
$('.parent').hover(function(){
    alert('parent');
})

$('.child').hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('child');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/93/)

Comment: This won't work as the mouse go through the parent first

Comment: @dystroy sorry I didn't get you, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

As your mouse goes through the parent first, you can't just use `stopPropagation` : the parent function would activate when the mouse is on the way to the child.

A solution in such a case is to use a timer : start the action only if the mouse stops over the parent without entering the child.

```
(function(){
    var timer;
    function p(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            alert('parent');
        }, 500);
    }
    $('.parent').hover(p, function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    })

    $('.child').hover(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }, p)
})();
```

[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/xywcadsq/)

Comment: I have this function here: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/13/

which I have tried combining with yours here: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/14/

my link is still not working (the word "some" )

Answer (score 0):

- Use `event.stopPropagation()`  it stops parent elements from knowing about a given event on its child.
- In your code use

  `$('.child').hover(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  })`
- **stopPropogation** on a child preventing any parent event handlers from being executed.

Comment: I tried... did not work. My child has an "onclick" function (onClick="function_name")